# pyspark: Merge multiple columns into one column but save the original column name

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe having many columns such as `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, and many more. Here only showing `v1` and `v2`. Only one of the columns with the prefix `v` will have a `real number` value, and all other columns have a null value.

I want to merge the columns starting with `v` into one column and create a corresponding column `cols` to show that value is from which original column. An example of the original table and resultant table are shown below.

Note: Original table has about 200 columns from `v1` to `v200` and over million rows.

`original table`

```
+---------+-----+----+-----+
|      org|   v1|  v2|count|
+---------+-----+----+-----+
|       Sh|   46|null|    2|
|       Sh|   41|null|    1|
|       Sh| null|   4|    3|
|       Fi|   30|null|    6|
|       Fi| null|   4|    2|
|       Xf| null|   2|    1|
|       Ai|   27|null|    1|
+---------+-----+----+-----+
```

`result table`

```
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
|      org|  val| cols|count|
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
|       Sh|   46|   v1|    2|
|       Sh|   41|   v1|    1|
|       Sh|    4|   v2|    3|
|       Fi|   30|   v1|    6|
|       Fi|    4|   v2|    2|
|       Xf|    2|   v2|    1|
|       Ai|   27|   v1|    1|
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Sample dataframe:

```
sample_data = (\
    ("Sh", 46, None, 2), \
    ("Sh", 46, None, 1),  \
    ("Sh", None, 4, 3),  \
    ("Fi", 30, None, 6),   \
    ("Fi", None, 4, 2),    \
    ("Xf", None, 2, 1),  \
    ("Ai", 27, None, 1),  \
             )
columns= [ "org", "v1", "v2", "count"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = sample_data, schema = columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
sample_data = (\
    ("Sh", 46, None, 2), \
    ("Sh", 46, None, 1),  \
    ("Sh", None, 4, 3),  \
    ("Fi", 30, None, 6),   \
    ("Fi", None, 4, 2),    \
    ("Xf", None, 2, 1),  \
    ("Ai", 27, None, 1),  \
             )
columns= [ "org", "v1", "v2", "count"]
columns_of_interest_count = 2
df = (
    spark.createDataFrame(data = sample_data, schema = columns)
    .withColumn('mapped_columns', f.map_filter(f.map_from_arrays(f.array([f.lit(f'v{str(i)}') for i in range(1, columns_of_interest_count + 1)]), f.array([f.col(f'v{str(i)}') for i in range(1, columns_of_interest_count + 1)])), lambda _, value: ~f.isnull(value)))
    .select('org', 'count', f.explode(f.col('mapped_columns')).alias('col', 'val'))
)
df.show(truncate= False)
```

output:

```
+---+-----+---+---+                                                             
|org|count|col|val|
+---+-----+---+---+
|Sh |2    |v1 |46 |
|Sh |1    |v1 |46 |
|Sh |3    |v2 |4  |
|Fi |6    |v1 |30 |
|Fi |2    |v2 |4  |
|Xf |1    |v2 |2  |
|Ai |1    |v1 |27 |
+---+-----+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of structs and filter that array to keep the structs that are non-null.

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('v_structs', 
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(k).alias('cols'), func.col(k).alias('vals')) 
                            for k in data_sdf.columns if k[0].lower() == 'v']
                          )
               ). \
    withColumn('v_having_value_structs', 
               func.expr('filter(v_structs, x -> x.vals is not null)')
               ). \
    select(*data_sdf.columns, func.expr('inline(v_having_value_structs)')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+----+----+-----+----+----+
# |org|v1  |v2  |count|cols|vals|
# +---+----+----+-----+----+----+
# |Sh |46  |null|2    |v1  |46  |
# |Sh |46  |null|1    |v1  |46  |
# |Sh |null|4   |3    |v2  |4   |
# |Fi |30  |null|6    |v1  |30  |
# |Fi |null|4   |2    |v2  |4   |
# |Xf |null|2   |1    |v2  |2   |
# |Ai |27  |null|1    |v1  |27  |
# +---+----+----+-----+----+----+
```

---

The array of structs would look like this

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('v_structs', 
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(k).alias('cols'), func.col(k).alias('vals')) 
                            for k in data_sdf.columns if k[0].lower() == 'v']
                          )
               ). \
    withColumn('v_having_value_structs', func.expr('filter(v_structs, x -> x.vals is not null)')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+----+----+-----+----------------------+----------------------+
# |org|v1  |v2  |count|v_structs             |v_having_value_structs|
# +---+----+----+-----+----------------------+----------------------+
# |Sh |46  |null|2    |[{v1, 46}, {v2, null}]|[{v1, 46}]            |
# |Sh |46  |null|1    |[{v1, 46}, {v2, null}]|[{v1, 46}]            |
# |Sh |null|4   |3    |[{v1, null}, {v2, 4}] |[{v2, 4}]             |
# |Fi |30  |null|6    |[{v1, 30}, {v2, null}]|[{v1, 30}]            |
# |Fi |null|4   |2    |[{v1, null}, {v2, 4}] |[{v2, 4}]             |
# |Xf |null|2   |1    |[{v1, null}, {v2, 2}] |[{v2, 2}]             |
# |Ai |27  |null|1    |[{v1, 27}, {v2, null}]|[{v1, 27}]            |
# +---+----+----+-----+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach.

```py
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

vcols = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('v')]

df = (df.select('*', F.coalesce(*vcols).alias('val'))
 .select('org', 'val', 'count', reduce(lambda p, c: p.when(F.col(c) == F.col('val'), F.lit(c)), vcols, F).alias('cols'))
)
```

First use `coalesce` to take the first non-null value amongst the columns of interest.

Then use chain of `when` to match find which columns have the same value as one that I got from `coalesce`.

This part

```py
reduce(lambda p, c: p.when(F.col(c) == F.col('val'), F.lit(c)), vcols, F)
```

will generate

```py
(F.when(F.col('v1') == F.col('val'), F.lit('v1'))
  .when(F.col('v2') == F.col('val'), F.lit('v2'))
  ...
)
```

So, this will give me the column name where the valid value come from.